# OpenCV/JavaCV - Fill canny contourn

Tags: opencv, javacv

I'm trying to fill the contourn with cvDrawContourns after cvFindContourns in cvCanny detection, but i'm not success in this

How can I fill the whole contourn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you request the function to fill the contours by passing the value CV_FILLED (which is equal to -1 if I remember correctly) to the thickness argument.  This is probably the same for the Java API.

Comment: I already tried it, but not success... It only painted the normal contourn but not filled...

Comment: Ok, maybe a specificity of the Java API... Can't help you then, sorry.